# How to create treeview like functionality using JavaScript on a table made of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, treeview

I am attempting to create a table out of divs with treeview like functionality. For example, the first row should be visible at first but when the node is clicked, the second level is shown and when the node on the second level is clicked, the third level is shown and so on. The table should also have cascading checkboxes. This should all be done through html, css and javascript. I've tried several things already, including these:

http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html

http://jsfiddle.net/Vd5BH/5/

The javascript seems to not be helping my cause at all. Also.. Interestingly enough, when I add javascript, it doesn't seem to work at all. What javascript would be ideal in this case? Even if you guys can't give me the answer, any pointer in the right direction can help. Here is my code. Let me know what you think.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Main.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="heading">
                <span class="col">Checkboxes</span>
                <span class="col"></span>
                <span class="col">Header 1</span>
                <span class="col">Header 2</span>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <span class="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0" /><label><input type="checkbox" id="cb" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0">Libraries</label>
                </span>
                <span class="col">Info 1</span>
                <span class="col">Info 1.2</span>
                <span class="col">Info 1.3</span>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row" id="div1">
                <span class="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0">Documents</label></span>
                <span class="col">Info 2</span>
                <span class="col"></span>
                <span class="col"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="table-row">
                <span class="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="node-0-0-0" checked="checked" /><label><input type="checkbox" /><span></span></label><label for="node-0-0-0">My Documents</label></span>
                <span class="col">Info 3</span>
                <span class="col"></span>
                <span class="col">Info 3.1</span>
            </div>
        </div>


    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
/*CSS for table*/

.container{
    display:table;
    width: 50%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align:center;
    }
 .heading{
     font-weight: bold;
     display:table-row;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 25px;
     font-size: 14px;
     font-family:georgia;

 }
 .table-row{  
     display:table-row;
     text-align: center;
 }
 .col{ 
    display:table-cell;
     border: 1px solid #000;
     padding: 1%;
 }

.container label[for]::before,
.container label span::before
{
    content: "\25b6";
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    color: #e74c3c;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 13px;
}

.container input[type="checkbox"]
{
    display: none;
}

.container label
{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container label[for]::before
{
    -webkit-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -ms-transform: translatex(-24px);
    -o-transform: translatex(-24px);
    transform: translatex(-24px);
}

.container label span::before
{
    -webkit-transform: translatex(16px);
    -moz-transform: translatex(16px);
    -ms-transform: translatex(16px);
    -o-transform: translatex(16px);
    transform: translatex(16px);
}

.container input[type="checkbox"][id]:checked ~ label[for]::before
{
    content: "\25bc";
}

.container input[type="checkbox"][id]:not(:checked) ~ ul
{
    display: none;
}

.container label:not([for])
{
    margin: 0 8px 0 0;
}

.container label span::before
{
    content: "";
    border: solid 1px #1375b3;
    color: #1375b3;
    opacity: .50;
}

.container label input:checked + span::before
{
    content: "\2714";
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25) inset;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Let me know what you guys think. This is turning out to be a challenging endeavor and I need to find out if something like this is even possible. Thanks to all.

EDIT: I have looked at the 3rd party tools suggested and that may be a possibility. But for the time being, I wrote my own javascript based on some more in depth research that I did. It works the way I want it to, but the problem is that the code isn't very dynamic. Is there any better way to write this:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //This piece of js is for the cascading check boxes
        $('.parent').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.child').prop('checked', true);
            }
            else {
                $('.child').prop('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //hide all of the 3rd level items (and potentially 4th level or lower)
        document.getElementById("childRail2").style.display = "none";

        //handle the node click event for the top level; this will target all of the children on the second level of the parent
        $('#node-0').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

                /*this targets a div that is intially hidden on startup, grabs all its inner elements and replaces the div with them
                  the point of the div is to hide all of the second level rows on startup*/
                var content = $("#extraControls").contents();
                $("#extraControls").replaceWith(content);

                $('.child-table-row').show(0);
            }
            else {
                $('#node-0').prop('checked', false);
                $('.child-table-row').hide(0),
                $('.child-table-row-2').hide(0);
                //returns the second level node to its original state
                document.getElementById("node-0-0").checked = false;
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        /*this handles the click event for the node on the second level so that the level under it will be shown/hidden
            this is not dynamic code, so for every subsequent level and every other second level node, this must be added and
            the id/class names replaced correctly*/
        if ($('#node-0-0').is(':checked')) {
            document.getElementById("div2").style.display = "none";
        }
        $('#node-0-0').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $('.child-table-row-2').show(0);
            }
            else {
                $('#node-0-0').prop('checked', false);
                $('.child-table-row-2').hide(0);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Let me know what you guys think of this. Thanks again for anyone who has the time to answer it.

Comment: Would you consider using a third party library to accomplish this?  Also, here is an example of a purely css treeview if you would prefer to not implement it with javascript: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu

Comment: Have you considered to use a shrink-wrapped solution instead of building your own ? You're tackling a major (imho) development task and unless you intend to teach yourself, develop widget libraries, or have special license requirements, there are several solutions around worth to be checked out ( eg. [webix](http://webix.com/demo/treetable/basic/), [jstree](http://www.jstree.com/demo/), [jqwidget](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxtreegrid/index.htm)  ).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. These solutions seem very possible, unfortunately, this may end up being commercial at some point and I may want to have this layout be used in future, potentially commercial, projects. I will however, take a deeper look into the links that both of you have provided. Thanks!